# Sending a part of a byte array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino

I am reading data from a serial port (in an Arduino) and framing it (syncing on a few bytes). To do that, I am reading the data into a big buffer.
Once I got the frame, I extract data and I want to send it to a different serial port using `serial.write` (`Serial.write(buf, len`)) which accepts a byte array and its size.

Since the data size can be random, I need something like a dynamic array (which is not recommended in Arduino). Any ideas?

Comment: If you already have it in a big array, why can't you just send the relevant part of it. You can point into the big buffer and use the length that contains the relevant part for sending. The only thing which you may not do is change the content of that buffer during sending.

Comment: Well, dynamic size is not recommended, but not forbidden ;) if you really need it you should use (being aware however that there are limitations). Most of the times, however, dynamic size can be replaced by making a maximized fixed-length array (for instance, if you can send a string from 2 to 16 chars, use a 16-char array). In this case, however, since you do not need to modify it just send the part of the array without duplicating (as dasblinkenlight replies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the data size can be random, I need something like a dynamic array

In C you rarely need a dynamic array, because arrays passed to functions do not carry their size with them. That is why all functions that take an array also take length.

Let's say you have your data inside `bigBuffer` at position `startPos`, and you wish to send `length` bytes. All you need to do is

```
Serial.write(&bigBuffer[startPos], length);
```

or with pointer arithmetic syntax

```
Serial.write(bigBuffer+startPos, length);
```

Comment: Thanks! I like simple solutions :)

Comment: @1qazxsw2 `length=endPosition-startPosition`, right? (add one if `endPosition` is inclusive).